# how to measure energy efficiency, latency and packet delivery ratio in contiki os?

Tags: contiki

Recently I have started working on Contiki OS. I am trying to analyze few parameters like energy efficiency, latency, delivery ratio etc with different deployment scenarios. I am using TelosB as the hardware platform.

Could you please suggest me how to calculate energy efficiency, latency, delivery ratio in Contiki OS?

Are there any sample codes available, which can be used to obtain these parameters ?

Comment: To measure energy you can use powertrace: http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11435067.pdf . And here is an example: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/powertrace/example-powertrace.c

Answer (score 0):

As watou suggests, powertrace is the first tool to try. It is an app you can find alredy in your Contiki installation and runs really simply and effectively. It can give you power consuption information (or more specifically, tx/rx/cpu/listen/idle states duration) and also sniff packets (then enabling the study on power loss and network performance).

To insert in your app you have to:

1) Add the powertrace APP in your Makefile ([like this](https://github.com/adamdunkels/contiki-fork/blob/master/examples/powertrace/Makefile#L2)),

2) Include `powertrace.h` in your main.c file,

3) Insert a call to `powertrace_start(CLOCK_SECOND * your_interval)` to print statistic periodically or put `powertrace_print("your label");` within your code.

Finally, if you want to navigate further you should put some sensing onto your circuit.